# Number of ways to colour a circle with $n$ (not prime) sections and $r$ colours

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

If two combinations differ only by rotation (but not reflection), then they are the same. In the original problem the given circle has $n=15$ sections. I've tried the following:

Count the number of ways to colour a 5 sectioned line:
$$r^5$$
Next, count using these $r^5$ colourings, ways to colour a $3$-sectioned circle:
$$\frac{(r^5)^3-r^5}3+r^5$$
However, I'm not sure this idea has taken into account all multiple countings.

Comment: In the first paragraph, do you mean $n=15$ sections?

Comment: @browngreen Yes, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) to efficiently count the number of colourings. For $n=15$:

- $r^{15}$ patterns are fixed under the identity rotation.
- $r^5$ are fixed under each of two order-3 rotations,
- $r^3$ under each of four order-5 rotations and
- $r$ under the remaining eight rotations.

Therefore the total number of rotationally distinct colourings for $n=15$ is
$$\frac{r^{15}+2r^5+4r^3+8r}{15}$$
More generally, for $n$ sections this number is
$$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nr^{\gcd(n,i)}$$